# Error: Unable to find the browser. "browserstack:Chrome@68.0:Windows 10" is not a browser alias or path to an executable file

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, cucumberjs, browserstack, testcafe

I have been having some issues in running some JavaScript tests via TestCafe. The project I have set up uses a BDD style and it invokes the TestCafe test runner to run the tests. I have integrated them using browserstack however, I am having when I run it from Jenkins. I keep getting this error and unable to resolve the issue as it's not even reaching BS servers.

I am able to run successfully from my local

Error log

```
[BrowserStack] BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME=natarajankrishna1

[BrowserStack] BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY=********************

[BrowserStack] BROWSERSTACK_BUILD=jenkins-H_QA_SPRINT_FEATURETESTS-363

[BrowserStack] BROWSERSTACK_LOCAL=true

[BrowserStack] BROWSERSTACK_LOCAL_IDENTIFIER=2abd3c29-8371-45c7-b28d-44fd7820fcd4-H_QA_SPRINT_FEATURETESTS__363

[31mF[39m[36m-[39m[36m-[39m[36m-[39m[36m-[39m[36m-[39m[36m-[39m[36m-[39m[31mF[39m[32m.[39m{ Error: Unable to find the browser. "browserstack:Chrome@68.0:Windows 10" is not a browser alias or path to an executable file.

    at /opt/jenkins2/jobs/H_QA_SPRINT_FEATURETESTS/workspace/node_modules/testcafe/src/browser/provider/pool.js:107:19

    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

    at step (/opt/jenkins2/jobs/H_QA_SPRINT_FEATURETESTS/workspace/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)

    at /opt/jenkins2/jobs/H_QA_SPRINT_FEATURETESTS/workspace/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:28:13

    at <anonymous> constructor: [Function: GeneralError] }
```

Comment: The error suggests that package ```testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack``` is missing in your CD environment

Comment: Please try to run the `testcafe -b browserstack` command with your testing environment. You should see the list of all browser configurations available on the Browserstack.
If you see an error, please check if  `testcafe` and `testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack` are installed both globally or both locally. I mean that both modules should be installed via the same command:

`npm i testcafe` and
`npm i testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack`

or

`npm i -g testcafe` and
`npm i -g testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack`

Comment: According to the [author's tweet](https://twitter.com/nkrishna79/status/1068435602432057345) he has managed to resolve the issue.